# Shell script hangs on mail command

Tags: shell, shell-script, mail-command

I'm finding that a call to the mail command is causing a script to suspend without error.  To close the script I have to ctrl-c or issue a kill command on the process id.

The pertinent section of the script is below:

```
EMAIL_TO="my@email.com"

if [ -f /www/archives/pdf/pdf_201207021048.tar ]; then
    echo "file exists"
else
    echo "file does not exist"
fi

echo "sending mail next..."

mail -s "pdfbackup" "$EMAIL_TO"

echo "mail sent?"
```

When running this, I'm seeing the text "sending mail next..." and nothing more.  It never returns to prompt.

I can see the script is still in memory with ps -ax | grep myscript.sh.

I've tried using quotes around the subject and email, and again without.  The same result is produced either way.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: also asked on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11298463/7552

Comment: @glennjackman - is there a preference for posting shell scripting questions?  I see more of it on SO, though they could also go here.

Comment: @acoder You can post on either (unix shell scripting is on-topic both on SO and here), but [not both](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `mail` program expects the user to type the message on its standard input (terminated by EOF (<kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>)).  You are not redirecting stdin, the program is waiting for input.  You can either redirect from `/dev/null` (for an empty message), from a canned file, or from a pipe, for example:

```
echo Hi, just sending you a message | mail -s "pdfbackup" "$EMAIL_TO"
```

or

```
mail -s "pdfbackup" "$EMAIL_TO" < /dev/null
```

Both of these should clear up problem.