# Bash script hangs on gotify push command in specific while/if loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian

I have a simple script I am building that monitors the auth.log for su/ssh sessions being opened. If it sees a session opened using su or ssh it sends a push message using Gotify. I have tested the Gotify command by putting it in its own script and running it and it works but as soon as it is in the while loop it just hangs. I have found a fix from this question [Shell script hangs on mail command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42145/shell-script-hangs-on-mail-command) by redirecting the input from /dev/null to the gotify command, but I am unsure why I need to do it in this particular instance and not when I use it in other scripts (I have a few other scripts where i use gotify without the redirect).

The script is:

```
#! /bin/bash
pipe=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo "${pipe}"
log="/var/log/auth.log"

trap "rm -f $pipe" EXIT

tail -f $log >> $pipe &

while read line;
  do
    aryLine=(${line})
    if [[ "${aryLine[@]:5:3}" =~ "pam_unix("(su|sshd)":session): session opened" ]]; then
      echo "session opened for ${aryLine[@]:10:4}"
     /usr/bin/gotify push -p 3 --title "login" "login from ${aryLine[10]}" < /dev/null
    fi
done < $pipe
```

I am at a loss why I need the /dev/null to stop the script hanging when using gotify within this particular while/if loop and any help understanding will be appreciated. The code below works and spams my gotify just fine:

```
#! /bin/bash
while true; do
  if true; then
    /usr/bin/gotify push -p 3 --title "login" "login from ${aryLine[10]}"
  fi
done
```

I am using Debian Bullseye.

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: Related: [SSH causes while loop to stop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66154/ssh-causes-while-loop-to-stop)

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks, that's a handy site. I have used them before for PHP, Javascript, and Regex, but didn't even think to search for one for bash scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `/dev/null` redirection because the whole `while .. do .. done < $pipe` compound command is set to read from the pipe, including the `gotify` command. The `gotify` command probably tries to read from its standard input (which is now a pipe) and blocks until it reaches end-of-file, which will only happen when `tail` terminates. `</dev/null` redirection allows you to run `gotify` disconnected from the pipe, so that it doesn't try to read from it.

I believe `gotify` behaves this way because it allows you to do things like:

```bash
echo "my message" | gotify push
```

It has to try reading its standard input to make this feature work.

Comment: ahh ok that makes sense why the test while loop worked as it wasn't redirected like the other one is.